# LaTeX \nomenclature shows now explanation

Tags: nomenclature

This is my code:

```
\usepackage{nomencl}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{.10\hsize}
\renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{#1 \dotfill}
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-2\parsep}
....
\printnomenclature
....
\nomenclature{UI}{Information Unit}
```

It *almost* produces the expected output, but, when translating to PDF, I only get the "IU" listed in the resulting file; the long version, "Information Unit", fails to appear. If, instead, I use

```
\nomenclature{UI} {Information Unit}
```

(note the blank space between the two arguments), the long version gets printed, but above or below the list of abbreviations.

What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

This code works as expected:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: nomencl
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\renewcommand{\nomname}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{.10\hsize}
\renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{#1 \dotfill}
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-2\parsep}

\begin{document}

\printnomenclature

\nomenclature{UI}{Information Unit}

\section{Xyz}

Abc

\end{document}
```

(the first three lines are for using `arara` that makes compilation simpler, but are not necessary).

[image]